# My trigger is not calling recursively

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, recursion, database-trigger

Below is my trigger , which is not called recursively could you please explain

```
USE [TESTING]
GO
/****** Object:  Trigger [dbo].[UPDATETRIGGER] ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[UPDATETRIGGER] on [dbo].[TEST]
 FOR UPDATE 
 AS
  UPDATE dbo.TEST
    SET lastEditedDate=GetDate()
    FROM INSERTED newdata
    WHERE TEST.MasterK = newdata.MasterK
```

Comment: What you mean by recursively?

Comment: Calling the trigger itself. Because the table that is updated inside is having the trigger.

Comment: Need the reason why it is not called recursively since this trigger is called when th TEST table is updated and now this trigger is updating the the TEST table.. so it again the table is updated and then so trigger is called since table is udpated .. now it should be cyclic but this not happening , i need the reason why it is not happening. and also below is the value of recursion and nested trigger when we do sp_configure  on the ms sql.. here we not turned off the property so why it not happening

Comment: server trigger recursion 0 1 1 1         nested triggers                 0 1 1 1

Answer (score 3):

**Nesting triggers and trigger recursion:**

By default, Adaptive Server allows nested triggers. To prevent triggers from nesting, use sp_configure to set the allow nested triggers option to 0 (off):

```
sp_configure "allow nested triggers", 0
```

Triggers can be nested to a depth of 16 levels. If a trigger changes a table on which there is another trigger, the second trigger fires and can then call a third trigger, and so forth. If any trigger in the chain sets off an infinite loop, the nesting level is exceeded and the trigger aborts, rolling back the transaction that contains the trigger query.

**Note:** Since triggers are put into a transaction, a failure at any level of a set of nested triggers cancels the entire transaction: all data modifications are rolled back. Supply your triggers with messages and other error handling and debugging aids to determine where the failure occurred.

The global variable @@nestlevel contains the nesting level of the current execution. Each time a stored procedure or trigger calls another stored procedure or trigger, the nesting level is incremented. The nesting level is also incremented by one when a cached statement is created. If the maximum of 16 is exceeded, the transaction aborts.

If a trigger calls a stored procedure that performs actions that would cause the trigger to fire again, the trigger is reactivated only if nested triggers are enabled. Unless there are conditions within the trigger that limit the number of recursions, this causes a nesting-level overflow.

For example, if an update trigger calls a stored procedure that performs an update, the trigger and stored procedure execute once if allow nested triggers is off. If allow nested triggers is on, and the number of updates is not limited by a condition in the trigger or procedure, the procedure or trigger loop continues until it exceeds the 16-level maximum nesting value.

**By default, a trigger does not call itself** in response to a second data modification to the same table within the trigger, regardless of the setting of the allow nested triggers configuration parameter. A set option, self_recursion, enables a trigger to fire again as a result of a data modification within the trigger. For example, if an update trigger on one column of a table results in an update to another column, the update trigger fires only once when self_recursion is disabled, but it can fire up to 16 times if self_recursion is set on. The allow nested triggers configuration parameter must also be enabled in order for self-recursion to take place.

Comment: Max @@nestlevel is 32 in sql-server

Answer (score 0):

One point to note is that, in SQL Server trigger is raised once per statement and NOT once per row. So, if your update statement updates more than one row, then the `Inserted` and `Deleted` pseudo tables will contain multiple rows. You may likely want to change your `UPDATE` statement like below

```
  UPDATE t
    SET lastEditedDate = GetDate()
    FROM dbo.TEST t
    JOIN INSERTED i ON t.MasterK = i.MasterK
```

Comment: no my trigger is not called recursively don't why , I need the reason why it is not called recursively .